# Can integer division yield a different result when applied on unsigned operands vs signed operands?

Tags: c, twos-complement, integer-division

I'm asking, of course, in terms of the actual "bit data" returned.

In other words, can the following function ever return `false`:

```
bool func(uint x, uint y)
{
    return x / y == (uint)((int)x / (int)y);
}
```

?

Comment: What exactly is `uint`? Why are you inventing your own typedef language instead of using standardized types?

Comment: Also, in obsolete C90 ("ANSI-C") there was a language bug where the rounding direction of division with negative numbers wasn't specified. This was fixed in 1999 and C90 was withdrawn. If you are using a very old compiler it could still be an issue.

Comment: The question is more about integer arithmetic than it is about C. It could just as well be C++, or any other strongly-typed language for that matter. I used C only in order to give a more concrete example of what I meant.

Comment: I just gave you a perfect example of why the exact language and version matters a lot. And neither C nor C++ has a type called `uint`. In either language, it also matters a lot what this type actually corresponds to. Implicit promotions and signed to unsigned conversions happen based on the size of the type. So it isn't meaningful to discuss this with some pseudo code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely it can. 4294967295 / 2 == 0x7fffffff, but -1 / 2 == 0.

The big value is of type `uint32_t` where all bits are set, and -1 is also a 32-bit value `int32_t` where all the bits are set. When the top bit of the parameters is set, you should expect different results. The exception is `a / a == 1`, for both signed and unsigned divisions, when `a != 0`.

The thing is that the compiler knows to emit a different instruction for the CPU, when the arithmetic is between signed vs unsigned operands.

Comment: It's a good answer, but I won't be passing `-1`, I'd be passing `(uint)(-1)`.

Comment: But you're right, it does answer the title of my question, so I'll need to dwell a bit on my logical confusion here...

Comment: When you pass `x=0xffffffff` as uint32_t, it's going to be -1 after the cast to `(int)x`.

Comment: Well, do you get when you call `func` with those values? I get the `true`... but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I was using it wrong (cout'ing `uint8`, which converted it into a `char`).